# android java ListAdapter adapter

Tags: java, android

Есть адаптер в который я загружаю данные с `ArrayList` нужно проверить если `item` имеет значение, допустим "красный" - то красим этот `item` в красный.

Искал примеры в интернете, нашел, но я не могу тогда туда передать `ArrayList` Ниже ссылка на пример в который не могу передать `ArrayList`

[habrahabr](https://habrahabr.ru/post/133575/)

```
ListAdapter adapter6 = new SimpleAdapter(mail.this,
                                         ArrayList,
                                         R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                                         new String[] { TAG_TEXT },
                                         new int[] { R.id.text1 });
```

Comment: Добавьте код вашего `SimpleAdapter`, пожалуйста

Comment: я такой же как у вас сделал

Comment: CustomArrayAdapter listAdapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(mail.this, messangelist, R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] { TAG_TEXT },
                 new int[] { R.id.text1 });

Comment: А что такое `messangelist`, `new String[] { TAG_TEXT }`  и `new int[] { R.id.text1 }` ?

Comment: public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> messangelist;

Comment: TAG_TEXT - это ключ в листе , это идентификатор куда вставлять полученный текст

Comment: Мы можем как  ни будь связаться я вам покажу ?

Comment: Напишите мне в телеграм https://t.me/vandrikeev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы передать в адаптер `ArrayList<String>` вам нужно реализовать у него конструктор, который будет принимать `List<String>` а не `String[]`.
Класс `ArrayAdapter<T>` имеет оба коснтруктора и вам нужно просто переопределить нужный.
Вот самый простой вариант нужного вам адаптера, который принимает оба вида коллекций:

```
public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    // для массивов
    public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, String[] objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }

    // для списков
    public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_layout, null, true);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);

        String item = getItem(position);
        textView.setText(item);
        if (item.contains("красный")) {
            textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        } else {
            textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Только не забудьте добавить `else` условие для случая, когда "не красный". Иначе при скроле получится каша и некоторые некрасные итемы будут окрашиваться красными.

Comment: @eugeneek спасибо, поправил

Comment: @eugeneek Кстати без `ViewHolder`'а всё-таки не будут =)

Comment: А вот и нет =) `ViewHolder` это чтобы `findViewById` не делать каждый раз. А ячейки и без него переиспользуются. `View convertView` вот это как раз и есть переиспользованная ячейка.

Comment: А в моём примере возвращается каждый раз новый `View`

Comment: Посмотрите внимательно. Новый `view` вы никак не используете.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60590/discussion-between-v-andrikeev-and-eugeneek).

Comment: У меня просит android studio просит создать такой конструктор 
Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> messangelist, int simple_list_item_1, String[] strings, int[] ints